# Php respond null with text file

Tags: php, mysql

Hy this is my database on altervista:

[db table picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVQM6.png)

I want to get the value of "profile" field; this field contains some text file. This is the php script to interact with my database:

```
<?php
require 'db.php';
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Errore in connessione al DBMS: ".mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
//$myusername='marco';
//$mypassword='marco';
$myusername=mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$mypassword=mysql_real_escape_string($password);

//$mypassword=md5($password);
$query = "SELECT userid, username , password , profilo FROM `utente` WHERE username='$myusername' AND password='$mypassword' LIMIT 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
if($result->num_rows >0)
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        $rows[]=$row;
}
header("Content-type: text/json");
echo json_encode($rows);
$result->close();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

However, in some case, I can get the value of profilo; in other case php response null even if the field isn't empty like this:

```
[{"userid":"1000002","username":"","password":"","profilo":null}].
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your table, user_id 1000002 has a null value in username and password.   All you are querying is for username and password, so those won't come up;  there's no way to identify them with your query as it is.

**Important Note**:  you are bouncing back and forth between `mysqli_` and `mysql_` functions.   As `mysql_` is deprecated (due to it being unsecure), you should be doing everything using `mysqli_` so you should really be using [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or better yet, [mysqli prepare statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [Prepared PDO statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

**Even more important, especially since your code is not secure**:  Don't store your passwords in plain text in your database.  Look into hashing and encryption.